# How long will the openid_id identifier be available through Google's OpenID connect service

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

We currently use the now deprecated OID2 service from Google to partially authenticate users to an account recovery service that we developed and maintain.  I understand we need to migrate to the new OpenID Connect service from Google by April 20, 2015.  Part of the migration includes mapping our old OID2 hashes (that we have stored as unique and thought to be permanent identifiers) to the new sub_id value available in the new service.  We understand that providing the openid_realm value to the new service will get us our OID2 hashes from the openid_id value, so that we can then map to the new sub_id.
Since we force users to annually verify their account recovery settings, we can force them to authenticate to Google at that time.  Considering the time frame for migration is less than a year, it will be difficult to accomplish full migration by April 15, 2015.  Our question is how long will the openid_id value in the new service return the old OID2 hashes for our realm?  Will it continue past the closing of the OID2 service?

Answer (score 6):

In order to maximize user-identifier migration rate (from OpenID to OAuth2/OpenID Connect), Google will continue to support the [identifier migration](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect) after OpenID2 is shut down in **April 2015**. Migration support will be available until **January 2017** (as per Google [migration timetable](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable)).